# Yii2 on Windows Server 2012r2 VM

Tags: php, yii2, windows-server-2012

for a client who has got windows server2012R2.
He want some project to be done regarding doctor and patient appointment etc., which I can do in Yii2, but am not sure, whether the same can be installed on windows server2012R2.

So anyone knows that it will work smoothly then I can accept the project else will deny it.

Answer (score 0):

First, install a WAMP environment in this platform, and then check the Yii requirements check tool with `php requirements.php` from the root directory of the project. By reading in the Yii forum (https://forum.yiiframework.com) you will find a lot of people running Yii2 apps on Windows. I'm 99% sure it should work as everything Yii depends on is multi platform.